# How to click button or view behind another activity in android

Tags: android, android-activity, kotlin, view

There is another MainActivity behind SubActivity. 
But the button in MainActivity is not pressed. How can I click?

MainActivity

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val intent = Intent(applicationContext, SubActivity::class.java)
    startActivity(intent)

    btn.setOnClickListener {
        Toast.makeText(this, "this is button", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}
}
```

SubActivity

```
class SubActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sub)
 }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button!"
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

   </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

activity_sub.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/keyboard_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="16dp">

<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello world"/>
 </RelativeLayout>
```

activity_sub.xml is Transparent and i wanna click button

Comment: Put your code to understand

Comment: Refer what is activity: (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity) I can help you if you tell me what you want to achieve.

Comment: put my code @MayurPanchal

Answer (score 0):

It seems you can't do this. As according to Android Activity Life Cycle whenever another activity comes on top of other activity. New Activity will be visible and other activity will not be visible. As there will not be any views visible you wont be able to achieve. Even if you try to call that method is will crash as view is not visible. Still If you can elaborate more on this problem and let me know your use.